# Why aren't the tab controls on my Razor page changing content when clicked?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I am trying to use tabbed pages within my project and the tabs are not working.  The tabs themselves appear to be working but the content is not switching when a tab is clicked.

I am using bootstrap 4 and I have researched this issue and it appears that everything is correct in code, but the tabs are not linked to the content that is defined.  Here is my code without the large form in the first tab.

```
<div class="container">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" href="#location">Location</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#address">Addresses</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#phone">Phones</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#contact">Contacts</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div class="tab-content">
        <div id="location" class="tab-pane fade show active">
[Form Code]
        </div>
        <div id="address" class="tab-pane fade show">
            <h3>Menu 1</h3>
            <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
        </div>
        <div id="phone" class="tab-pane fade">
            <h3>Menu 2</h3>
            <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam.</p>
        </div>
        <div id="contact" class="tab-pane fade">
            <h3>Menu 3</h3>
            <p>Eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Looking at the console I am receiving the following error:

> jquery.min.js:1251 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).bootstrapMaterialDesign is not a function

I do not know how or if this would impact my issue.

Comment: Is this bootstrap? Where is your javascript code for the same?

Comment: Check console might be you get error over there.

Comment: It is bootstrap 4

Comment: Your code is correct nothing wrong check this: https://jsfiddle.net/kalpeshboghara/Ldzxp6s9/2/

Comment: I am receiving an error within the jquery.min.js file but I have no idea how to debug it...

Comment: Please add your error into question so someone can help.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue.  I was missing a javascript in my build.  Thanks to Kalpesh for pointing out that my code was correct.  It got me looking at other possibilities...